# Get the iframe value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, codemirror

I have an iframe that I append User-written HTML, CSS, and JS code.
I can compile the code and return errors, but how can I get the actual result of the run?
for example, if the user-written code is BLAH it will return BLAH. so how can i get it?
I tried using this function:

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById("test");
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

But it returns the  tag.
The iframe is not cross-domain btw.
Code:
Iframe:

```
<div class="code-result">
     <iframe class="result" id="test" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     <div class="console"></div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
    window.addEventListener('load',function() {
        $(document).ready(
            function (){
                $('.compile').click(function () {
                    var myIFrame = document.getElementById("test");
                    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                    html_result = content.substring(content.indexOf(0),content.indexOf('<script>'));
                    if (html_result == 'ds') {
                        alert('True!')
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Try again.')
                    }
                })
            }
        )
    })
```

Comment: [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: @Lain What do you mean by that? can you add a real use-case that fits my needs?

Comment: Please make [mre]  in SO snippet or outside fiddle.